# Spring 4 + data-jpa + hibernate 5: At least one JPA metamodel must be present

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My goals was to make a simple example of a web app working with Hibernate 5 + Spring Data JPA repositories. Unfortunately, spring boot is not an option in my case, and XML configurations is preferred.
I am trying to figure out how to make this work, but it looks like spring data + jpa cannot scan the entities properly.

All I get is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext':
```

And:

```
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
```

From what I understood, based on spring documentation, there is no need for a jpa persistence.xml file.

Here is my setup:

My Entity:

```
package br.com.test.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TESTE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_TEST_CD_TESTE", sequenceName = "SQ_TEST_CD_TESTE")
public class Teste {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SQ_TEST_CD_TESTE")
@Column(name = "TEST_CD_TESTE", precision = 10, scale = 0)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "TEST_TX_TEXTO", length = 400)
private String texto;

@Column(name = "TEST_DT_DATA")
private LocalDateTime data;

@Column(name = "TEST_NM_NUMERO", precision = 10, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal numero;
```

Spring Configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.test.persistence"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.test.business"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.test.persistence"/>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="applicationDS"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes>-->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.test.entity"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace instead of a snippet. You are also using JDK8 date/time types for that to work with hibernate you need to add the `hibernate-java8` dependency.

Comment: About the `hibernate-java8` dependency, in version 5.2 it's not necessary anymore. For the full stacktrace, I feel kind of stupid now because it's working and I really did not change any major configuration. Anyway, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Then why does a `hibernate-java8` jar for 5.2 still exists... afaik there still is no way in hibernate (without that jar) to have a jdk8 date/time stored in the db and read back...

Comment: I can tell you that it's working right now, but I agree with you, it's awkward to have an updated version of a deprecated dependency.

Comment: Aren't you just lucky due to the type of column? What is the column type you use?

Comment: It's an ordinary [DATE] column on Oracle.